# JavaScript Validation error on page, but can move to next step

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a datepicker, if the user picks a date that is grater than 5 years the following error message should appear *"You are ineligible for our program",* the user cannot move to the next step if this error message appears.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" id="CitizenDate">
   <div class="col-md-6 ">
     <label class="control-label " style="color:black; font-size:13px;text-align:left;"> Citizen Since:<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker_recurring" placeholder="-- Citizen Since --" id=CitizenSince name="CitizenSince" style="max-width:190px;margin-top:2px;" data-val-regex-pattern="^([0]?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$" data-val-regex="Invalid Date" data-val="true" required />
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="Citizen_Err"></span>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
    $('#CitizenSince').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1980:2030"
    });

    $("#CitizenSince").on('change', function () {
        var reg = new RegExp('^([0]?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$');
        var date = Date.parse($(this).val());
        var dtV = $(this).val();
        var exploded = dtV.split("/");
        var d = new Date(exploded[2], exploded[1] - 1, exploded[0]);
        $('#Citizen_Err').hide();
        if (!reg.test($(this).val())) {
            var errorid = $(this).attr('id') + 'Error';

            $('#Citizen_Err').text('Incorrect Date Format. Please use "dd/mm/yyyy" Format.');
            isvalid = false;
            $('#Citizen_Err').show();

        } else {
            var currentYear = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()))

            if (currentYear.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear() > 5) {
                var errorid = $(this).attr('id') + 'Error';
                $('#Citizen_Err').text('You are ineligible for the program');
                isvalid = false;
                $('#Citizen_Err').show();
            }

        }

    });
```

When I test this code, the error message does appear, but I can still move to the next step. If I choose the wrong format of the date for example: "mm/dd/yyyy", the wrong Date format msg appears and I can't move to the next step. How do I prevent the user from moving to the next step if I choose a date greater than 5 years?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose  the invalid date is actually handled by jquery datepicker plugin itself and hence the focus is staying (I could be wrong).

But the custom logic is not restricting the datepicker in any way as the date is still valid as far as datepicker plugin is concerned.

Try to move your custom validation into a new function and handler the blur event of the datepicker, something like shown below.

```
$('#CitizenSince').on('blur',function(){
  var result = yourCustomValidation(this);
  if (!result) {
     $('#CitizenSince').focus();  // something link this
  }
});
```

There may be better solution, but until someone post it, please give this approach a try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

```
if (currentYear.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear() > 5)
```

It should be

```
if (d.getFullYear() - currentYear.getFullYear() > 5)
```

[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/y6uh4os1/43/)